# Segmentation Fault on PThread Malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

First let me start by posting the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//64 BITS -ALL 32 bit Arch
//32 BIT - UNIX 64 bit arch
//64 BIT - WINDOWS 64 bit arch
long long sum = 0;
static enum turn
{
  PING,
  PONG
}def;

struct threads_util
{
  pthread_t *t_id;
  pthread_attr_t *attr;
  void (*init_attr)(pthread_attr_t *);
}; 

void init_attr_fn(pthread_attr_t *attr)
{
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
}

void* sum_runner(void* arg)
{
    long long* limit_ptr = (long long *) arg;
    long long limit = *limit_ptr;//Derefrencing
    for(long long i=0; i<=limit; i++)
        sum += i;
    printf("Sum is %lld \n", sum);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void ping()
{
  puts("Ping");
  def = PONG;
}

void pong()
{
  puts("Pong");
  def = PING;
}

pthread_t * all_thread(pthread_t *t_id)
{
  t_id = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
  return t_id;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc<2)
    {
    puts("Usage ./objFile <num 1> <num 2> .. <num n>"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    int args = argc-1;
    long long limit = atoll(argv[1]);
    def = PING;

   struct threads_util *threads[args];

   for (int i=0; i<args; i++)
    threads[i]->t_id = all_thread(threads[i]->t_id);
    puts("In");    
   for(int i=0; i<args; i++)
   {
      threads[i]->init_attr = init_attr_fn;

      threads[i]->init_attr(threads[i]->attr);
      pthread_create(threads[i]->t_id,threads[i]->attr,sum_runner,&limit);
   }

    //Begin -Main Functions
    for(int i=0; i<= 10; i++)
    {
    if(def == PING)
           ping();
        else if(def == PONG)
           pong();
        else
           puts("UNKOWN PI-PO");           
    }
    //End - Main Functions

    for(int i=0; i<args; i++)
    {
      pthread_join(threads[i]->t_id,NULL);
    }
}
```

You can see i have a puts("In"), in the main function, just after the for loop when i call all_thread args times. Well calling the function argc times with the for loop according to my debugging skills, is the problem. And also before we did all the allocation strategy, I had a problem on calling the thread function, of course resulting in a Segmentation Fault. `threads[i]->init_attr(threads[i]->attr);`. Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct threads_util *threads[args];
```

means that you define an array of **pointers** to `struct threads_util`. But you don't actually create any `struct threads_util` so this line:

```
threads[i]->t_id = all_thread(threads[i]->t_id);
```

is illegal as it writes to memory not allocated.

You need to allocate memory for `struct threads_util` first:

```
for (int i=0; i<args; i++)
    threads[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct threads_util));
```

Comment: Ok im pass that problem.. Can you go on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c ? right now i have a problem with initalizing the attributes: threads[i]->init_attr(threads[i]->attr);

Comment: Seems that `threads[i]->attr` isn't initialized - maybe you should just initialize it to `NULL`

Comment: I Have Defeated the Segmentation Fault Monster!!!! Should i post correct solution>

Comment: You are always allowed to answer your own question. Normally it is only done when the solution isn't covered by an existing answer and when you think that your own answer will be helpful for others.